# How can I fix this error at Eclipse for JAVA?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse give error when I try to compile and run to JAVA codes. The error is

> "The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches".

How to fix this issue ??
[image: The error is here...]

Comment: Write a class with `public static void main( String[] args){...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is wrong. you need a main method to launch your program

```
package main;

public class main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

Note: The name of the class always has to be the name of the file, and typically java classes start with an uppercase letter

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run main first and describe your problem in more detail if you still have a problem.

Q: When I try to run my project by clicking the green "Play" button, I get an error of, "The Selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches."

A: See previous question. You must run your project's "Main" class at least once by using the right-click method described above, before the "Play button" to run a project will work.

http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/15wi/eclipse_tutorial/faq.shtml